# how to convert date 2017-sep-12 To 2017-09-12 in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am facing one issue in converting the date in hive. I need to convert 2017-sep-12 To 2017-09-12 . How can i achieve this in HIVE

Comment: Tried anything from here? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern)` to convert given date format to seconds passed from 1970-01-01. Then use `from_unixtime()` to convert to given format:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-sep-12' ,'yyyy-MMM-dd'), 'dd-MM-yyyy');
OK
12-09-2017
```