# In SQL How to convert time into UNIX timestamp

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, unix-timestamp

In hive there is some data I have. Now I want to convert the `start_timestamp` into `unix_timestamp` in second. How to do that? Because the `start_timestamp` has two formats:

First format:

```
    2018-03-22 02:54:35
```

Second format:

```
    May 15 2018  5:15PM
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: What data type is the column `start_timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First format is `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`, second is `'MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:aa'`. If the format is wrong, `unix_timestamp` function will return `NULL`. Try to convert using one format, if `NULL`, try to convert using the other format. This can be done using `coalesce` function:

```
select 
      coalesce(unix_timestamp(start_timestamp ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),
               unix_timestamp(start_timestamp ,'MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:aa')
              ) as UnixTimestamp
  from my_table;
```

Use `from_unixtime()` to convert it back to given format if necessary, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47301792/2700344).

See patterns examples here: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)